# ASP.NET Core MVC: get token to call downstream API: Can't resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IAuthorizationHeaderProvider'

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, token

I am following this tutorial from MSFT:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore

Based on the following code I should be able inject the `IAuthorizationHeaderProvider` and get the token:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    readonly IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authorizationHeaderProvider;

    public HomeController(IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authorizationHeaderProvider)
    {
        this.authorizationHeaderProvider = authorizationHeaderProvider;
    }

    // Code for the controller actions (see code below)

}
```

Then use `IAuthorizationHeaderProvider` in the controller:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
{
    // Acquire the access token.
    string[] scopes = new string[]{"user.read"};
    string accessToken = await 
    authorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(scopes);
    ...
}
```

Also per the documentation:

> Your web app needs to acquire a token for the downstream API. You specify it by adding the .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() line after .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration). This line exposes the IAuthorizationHeaderProvider service that you can use in your controller and page actions. However, as you see in the following two options, it can be done more simply. You also need to choose a token cache implementation, for example .AddInMemoryTokenCaches(), in Startup.cs:

I have added this code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]{"user.read" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

However, I get the following error when running the project:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Identity.Abstractions.IAuthorizationHeaderProvider' while attempting to activate

Comment: Sorry I didn't reproduce your issue as every thing worked well in my side, I test with a new .net 7 mvc application with microsoft identity platform authentication type, and adding the code snippets into my project, and everything worked well. If you are just in the beginning of your project, you might also try to create a new project to reduce your time of troubleshoting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this exception should relate to DI, at first I was thinking about  that it might due to an old version of `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, however when I test with version 1.16.0, I got compile exception. If I upgrade to the latest stable version, everything worked fine and failed to reproduce your issue.

Here's my test result.

[image]

I think you might first checking the nuget packages version, upgrade to the lateset and rebuild your app. Here's mine:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.13.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.13.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Or you might create a new project with the VS template and choose Microsoft Identity platform as the Authentication type. Then modify the Program.cs and your controller with the code snippet you shared in the question, then fill the fields in the appsettings.json with the value you got from Azure AD. Do not forget to add the ClientSecret, the default template doesn't provide the `ClientSecret` field.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you Tiny, the issue was that the Visual Studio template uses Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.16.0.  Note to self and everyone else, always update your NUGET packages first.  Many thanks for the detailed response with images.